# Can I change A-Frame component's attribute (loop from false to true) in the console?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, console, aframe

I am trying to build a simple scene with A-Frame in JS to excercise the basics([codepen](https://codepen.io/JammingJack/pen/YzyEwbZ)). So far so good I got the geometry like I want it, not perfect but it's ok.

```
<a-cylinder position="-4.8 1 0" radius="0.2" height="2" color="slategray">
    <a-cylinder position="0 1.5 0" radius="0.15" height="1.5" color="slategray">
        <a-box position="-1 0.5 0" width="2" height="0.5" depth="0.3" color="slategray">
            <a-circle cursor-listener id="green" position="-0.5 -0.03 0.17" color="#196f3d " radius="0.2"></a-circle></a-circle>
            <a-circle cursor-listener id="yellow" position="0 -0.03 0.17" color="#7d6608 " radius="0.2"></a-circle>                    
            <a-circle cursor-listener id="red" position="+0.5 -0.03 0.17" color="#641e16" radius="0.2"></a-circle>
        </a-box>
    </a-cylinder>
</a-cylinder>
<a-ring position="0 0 0" rotation="-90 0 0 " color="gray" radius-inner="5" radius-outer="7">

<a-sphere id="car" position="-0 -1 0.4" radius="0.01" animation="property:rotation;to:0 0 -360; easing:linear; dur:5000;loop:false;autoplay:false">
    <a-box position="-5.5 0 0" width="0.4" height="0.4" depth="0.4" ></a-box>
</a-sphere>



</a-ring>
```

I can make the rectangle orbit around the center of the scene, but what i want to do is make the animation a click event based, so I though of switching the `loop attribute` from `false` to `true`.
i went ahead and tried it in the `console` but nothing changed.

```
var s=document.getElementById("car")
s.components.animation.animation.loop=true
```

Note: I've also changed the `autoplay` to `false` and tried switching it back from the `console` by executing

```
var s=document.getElementById("car")
s.components.animation.animation.autoplay=true
```

but again nothing changed.
I think I misunderstood some in the [documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/animation.html#boolean-values), I'm not sure exactly.
Can somebody please help me.

---------------------------------EDIT------------------------

I've added these events setting to the animation attribute of the the parent of component of my box

```
startEvents: rotation-start; pauseEvents: rotation-pause; resumeEvents: rotation-resume;
```

e.g :

```
<a-sphere id="car" position="-0 -1 0.4" radius="0.01" animation="property:rotation;startEvents: rotation-start; pauseEvents: rotation-pause; resumeEvents: rotation-resume;to:0 0 -360; easing:linear; dur:5000;loop:true;">
    <a-box position="-5.5 0 0" width="0.4" height="0.4" depth="0.4" ></a-box>
</a-sphere>
```

so now  I can play/pause the animation in the browser console using :

```
var e=document.getElementById("car")
e.components.animation.animation.play()

e.components.animation.animation.pause()
```

but trying to do it inside script tag so that i can utilize the cursor-listener event doesn't work :

```
<script>
     AFRAME.registerComponent('cursor-listener', {
      update: function () {
            this.el.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
                var car=document.getElementById("car");
                if(this.id=="red"){
                    car.components.animation.animation.pause()

                }
                if(this.id=="green"){
                    console.log(this.data);
                    this.components.animation.animation.play()
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

throws error:

> TypeError: this.components.animation is undefinedtraffic_light.html:23:21

---------------------------------------------------EDIT N°2-------------------------

I fixed it , here is the new js :

```
    <script>



      AFRAME.registerComponent('cursor-listener', {
  update: function () {
        this.el.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
            var car=document.getElementById("car_origin");
            if(this.id=="red"){
                car.components.animation.animation.pause()

            }
            if(this.id=="green"){
                car.components.animation.animation.play()
            }
        });
    }
});
  </script>
```